# Empty state from a handler function in React (with datatables)

Tags: reactjs, datatables

I am using datatables.net plugin with React. I generate a button in the last column of every row using the following parameter in columnDefs of the datatables:

```
            {
            "targets": [10],
            createdCell: (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) => {
                ReactDOM.render(
                        <button onClick={props.handleReportClick}></button>
                    , td);
                }
            })
```

Within my react page, I have the following:

```
const handleReportClick = (e) =>{
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(dataTable);
};
```

The console.log above gives me empty string (there is a hook [dataTable, setDataTable] on the page which has values immediately after initiation of the datatable) and same happens for all other hook values on that page. All other event handlers on the page console.log(dataTable) as an object and can access all state but not this one.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that passing reference to the handler function to the button (as in my example above) was giving me all sorts of problems with the handler function referencing wrong render instances. Instead, I provided each button with a unique data-id (in my case row was enough as I only have one button in a row) and then created a useEventListener hook to add event listener to all clicks on the page. I also added the below function to get the data-id of the button that was clicked as the event listener was unreliable and yielded child elements as targets. Below works well and captures data-id each time. This way, the state that I access for dataTable is correct and I can capture info from datatable's appropriate row and process it.

```
export default function getSelectedRow(e) {
    let parent = e.target;
    let selectedRow;
    while (parent) {
        if (parent.getAttribute('data-id')) {
            selectedRow = parent.getAttribute('data-id');
        }
        parent = parent.parentElement;
    }
    return selectedRow;
}
```